# Order Data only by Price in Flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Query:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products')
  .where('dateOfExpiry', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: DateTime.now())
  .orderBy('dateOfExpiry')
  .orderBy('price', descending: false);
```

I'm using Flutter with Firebase to fetch data from a collection of products.
My condition here is to fetch data of the products which are not expired in order from lowest price to highest price.
But I don't want to order it by the date of expiry.
As in flutter, I need to put order by on the column for which I'm using inequality operator i.e. "dateOfExpiry".

Otherwise I get this error:

> The initial orderBy() field "[[FieldPath([price]), false]][0][0]" has to be the same as the where() field parameter "FieldPath([dateOfExpiry])" when an inequality operator is invoked. 'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart': Failed assertion: line 252 pos 18: 'field == orders[0][0]'

Any solution for this will be appreciated.

Comment: have u found a solution?

Comment: To achieve this, I had to create a function in which I compared my product's date with today and put a condition to check if it is expired. If the product is not expired it will be stored in the new list which I built with ListView Builder.